# Mac OSX Audio keyboard

Tags: macos, audio-recording, speech-to-text

I am creating an application that will pre-record a user's voice for each letter on the keyboard and when the app is running, if the user calls out '5', the system types 5 to which ever application is capable of accepting the input at that time. I am .NET person and venturing into XCode.

I have done some research and I am pretty sure of using AV Foundation for recording the audio. The question is how to use speech recognition in OSX and use it to identify a particular key on the keyboard...Will highly appreciate any feedback even if it might be general advice for the approach that I should take to tackle this project!

ThankS IN ADVANCE :) !

Comment: Look in my edited answer. There is a pre-build speech recognizer in OSX. If you want to make your own, you can use my way with the server etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Let me be clear first. I have never done this before, but i have a general idea of how it is done. You need to Bind a audio file to a certain number/Key. Whenever a user speaks into the mic, you record their voice and upload it to a server, which compares the Audio File from the User to the pre recorded audio file the user made.

Here is a SO Question that talks about Audio Fingerprinting.

[How can I Compare 2 Audio Files Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979352/how-can-i-compare-2-audio-files-programmatically)

You can compare the audio files in PHP/Python, and have it return a value. For example. If audio file a.mp3 (on server) matches to the newRecorded.mp3 the user just recorded, return a.mp3, then just strip the .mp3 and keep the key.

As far as recording sentences and commands, you might be able to do the same. I will continue to do more research on this and help you out as much as i can.

Hopefully this gives you a better idea and easier way of doing things.

Also there is this 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/speech/Articles/RecognizeSpeech.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002081-BCIHEBFH

This could be really helpful and would use built in speech recognition.